# Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have a project using the maps with markers in here API. I copied the code from the old project and pasted on the new one but it started giving me this error:

```
Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://developer.here.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘http://127.0.0.1:5500’).
```

Here is the code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'https://developer.here.com'</script>
    <script src='https://developer.here.com/javascript/src/iframeheight.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        
        <script>
      /**
 * Moves the map to display over Berlin
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: 'i put my api key here'
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:xxx, lng:xxx},
  zoom: 4,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
window.onload = function () {
  moveMapToBerlin(map);
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sincerely confused. I tried checking my API key, changing longitude and latitude, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'https://developer.here.com'` to `window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'` in the 5th `<script>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'</script>
    ...
```

Comment: why is it 5500 port?